# small program much slower in visual studio 2012 vs. visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2012

We are using Visual Studio 2005.  We are looking at maybe upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 once it is released.  I tried this small program in Visual Studio 2012 RC and was surprised to see it ran more than 2X slower than it does in Visual Studio 2005.  In VS2012 I used default release build settings.  For me it takes about 20ms in VS2005 and about 50ms in VS2012.  Why is it that much slower?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

deque<int> d;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int COUNT = 5000000;

    timeBeginPeriod(1);    

    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
    {
        d.push_back(i);
    }

    double sum = 0;

    DWORD start = timeGetTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
    {
        sum += d[i];
    }

    printf("time=%dms\n", timeGetTime() - start);

    printf("sum=%f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Chances are you didn't compile them the same way.

Comment: Recommendation:  Do not use `std::deque` if you use or may use the Visual C++ Standard Library.  It has [abysmal performance characteristics.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607710/151292)

Comment: try to go for out of range error and see if VS 2012 shows assert.  They have some checking enabled, it is possible that you disabled it in 2005 and enabled it in 2012   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Both x86, both optimization settings seems the same (the 2012 project was converted from the 2005 one).  Will trying other suggestions soon.

Comment: Okay in 2005: whatever setting I use for "Enable C++ Exceptions" it runs the same, about 20ms.  For 2012 if I disable exceptions it goes from about 50ms to 23ms or so.  So 2005 handles having exception on better, in this case? That would still be disappointing, we run with exceptions on usually.

Comment: You could be hitting this problem:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/738031/calling-c-function-with-a-try-catch-block-is-much-slower-even-if-no-exception-is-thrown#details   try compiling the attached test cpp file in 2005 and in 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we reposted this question to the Microsoft forum. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/72234b06-7622-445e-b359-88f572b4de52

The short answer is that the implementation of std::deque::operator[] in VS2012RC is just slower compared to VS2005.  Other common stl containers tested as equal or faster.    It will be interesting to retest when VS2012 is production to see if the operator[] performance is resolved.

ps
Hi Raphael
Karl

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that you're running into thread-safety code and that 2012 configures your libraries for multi-threaded code by default, meaning there are a bunch of lock and unlock operations built into your deque accesses.

Try comparing the compiler and linker options of the two builds to see how they differ.

(I'd try this myself but I don't have a Windows system with the relevant software on it handy.  Sorry.)

Comment: Please tell me you're on pure theory here, and that MS didn't change the STL to be thread-safe by default or something.  That would seem to be... an interesting feature that should really *really* be documented somewhere.

Comment: Why would `std::deque` require internal synchronization?

Comment: This is pure guesswork.  However, I vaguely remember something similar happening with std::string between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try timing both of those loops separately. I bet the issue is that the stl container implementation is slower in the new compiler.

Err wait- I meant try timing something that doesn't use STL.

Comment: There are two variables here - speed of the compiler and speed of STL. I'm suggesting eliminating one variable. And yes - I'm betting STL is the likely culprit.